# Парсинг строки JSON

Tags: c#, json, парсер, json.net

В командную строку выходит JSON ответ в переменной responce. Почему у меня не парсится определенная строка из responce

```
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(packet, 0, packet.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            do
            {
                int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                response.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
            }
            while (stream.DataAvailable); // пока данные есть в потоке

            // Закрываем потоки
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());

            var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);

            string name = m.Key;
```

Comment: у вас не парсится какая то строка, но вы её не показываете

Comment: и я не понял, зачем вы пытаетесь строку десериализовать в строку?

Comment: У меня строка response выводит на экран json строку. В ней есть поле "key":"long_example", как мне пропарсить ее чтобы записать в name "long_example" ?

Comment: Бред какой-то... Пишете в stream какие-то данные и тут же из него читаете. Эти же данные хотите прочитать? / Flush() сбрасывает буфер, но не перематывает поток в начало.

Comment: Предлагаю упростить вопрос. Уберите код работы с потоком. Я так понял, вы же успешно получаете данные из него? Покажите только имеющуюся строку с данными JSON и укажите, что хотите в итоге получить.

Comment: Так вычитывать utf-8 нельзя. В нем символ может занимать несколько байт, и на итерации может попасть на середину символа. И точно нельзя читать из сокета по признаку DataAvailable - это флаг означает, что данные дошли в буфер сокета. А не "удаленный хост больше ничего не отправил". Хост может отправить, но данные не успеют дойти - и ваш код оборвет соединение. Причем это обязательно выстрелит вживую при работе по сети, но никогда не выстрелит на локальной машине. Правильно - накапливать весь ответ в буфер как байты (MemoryStream), и переставать читать тогда, когда Read вернет 0.

Comment: ZBXD☺[       {"response":"success","data":[{"key":"long_example","delay":30,"las_tlogsize":0,"mtime":0}]}
Запрос завершен...
Приходит вот это. Мне нужно в переменную Key записать long_example